# how to redirect to parent route from children route in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I created child router in my router configuration and configured my child router in way that it redirects to parent router component. But the configuration doesn't work as expected. Instead it redirects to error page as it didn't find the configured path.

My app.route.ts file

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// Component
import { HomeRouterComponent } from '../../modules/home/homerouter.component';
import { ChannelComponent } from '../../modules/channels/channel.component';

import { ErrorComponent } from '../../modules/errorPage/error.component';



const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeRouterComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginCheck]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'channel',
    component: ChannelComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'channel',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why you have a child route without a path? But since it's not an actual path, you wouldn't need to redirect anywhere, since there is no change in url. I had a similar setup where I did not want to show a child initially upon navigation. Leaving it empty worked fine for me, so try:

```
  {
    path: 'channel',
    component: ChannelComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
      }
    ]
  }
```